# How do I trim space in primeNg Dropdown (p-dropdown) filter in angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, dropdown, primeng

I have used primeNg dropdown (p-dropdown) in my angular 5 project but when I try to filter dropdown data and I give the space after that dropdown shows the **No Results Found** so How can I solve that?

e.g. I have country dropdown and if I search for India with space before and after that in the filter p-dropdown showing **No Results Found** message.

I simply want to trim() the searched string in primeng p-dropdown filter

Here is the code of html of p-dropdown:

```
<p-dropdown (onChange)="checkType(model.transectionType)" *ngIf="availableBalance != 0.00" (keydown)="onKeyUp($event)" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [options]="transectionType" [filter] = "true"
            [resetFilterOnHide] = "true" [(ngModel)]="model.transectionType" 
            [formControl]="form.controls['transectionType']" placeholder="Select a Transaction type" 
            optionLabel="value"></p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution but it is complicate one.
So basic thing here is when we use `<p-dropdown>` in our angular app with `[filter]="true"` then it will have the keydown method for filter defined in ng_modules->primeng->components->dropdown->dropdown.js so to trim the serched/filtered value from right and left we need to add .trim() at inputValue like this: `this.filterValue = inputValue.trim();`

Primeng should add this in their core code of dropdown so we don't need to fix that additionally and won't get this issue further.

Answer (score 0):

**in primeng 15 and angular 15 :**

html file

```
<p-dropdown (onFilter)="onFilter($event)" [filterValue]="filterValue">
```

ts file

```
filterValue: string = '';
onFilter(event) {
    this.filterValue = '';
    this.filterValue = CommonHelper.CorrectWrongCharacters(event.filter);
  }
```